# Save only part of objects in Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**Problem:** I'm implementing aplication where user is dowloading lots of objects in xml. To reduce peak memory footprint I want to parse data to Core Data and then use batching to display them in table view. I don't want them to be saved anyhow because objects will be changing everyday but I want to let user choose its favourites object and then save them. Favourites will be displayed in different table view.

**Solutions I'm thinking about:**

1. Create two NSManagedObjectContext (one main and one tmp). Parse objects to tmp, if its marked as favourite copy object to main and save it from there.
2. Forget about memory and keep data in some array and save only choosen ones.
3. Save all using one NSManagedObjectContext and before application will terminate delete unmarket as favourites.

Any hint here would be nice. Also some code sample code with solution one because I'm new to Core Data and I may have problems. I've been looking for suitable solution for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you forget about optimizing the memory footprint unless/until you have some hard evidence showing that this will in fact be needed. But of course it depends on what "lots of objects in xml" means exactly.

I am assuming you are not downloading millions of XML documents just to throw them away again when the application finishes (because that would be a serious waste of network resources). In contrast, an array with a few hundred or even a few thousand small XML-like data structures would most likely be nothing to worry about as far as memory is concerned.

That being said, if you would need to save both temporary and persistent data with Core Data after all, I would go for a single NSManagedObjectContext with two entities rather than two separate contexts. Or you could even have a single entity and mark certain instances as temporary data. Managing two different contexts means additional overhead while I don't really see any advantages to that approach.

Comment: Is there a way to use entity (subclass of NSManagedObject) as temporary data? How is it usually done when you download temp data and save only part of them to core data?

Comment: I would just save everything to the database and then delete the temporary data when I no longer need it.